# what is protocol for submission and verification assignment securely

Tags: security, blockchain, hash-function

Prof. Palam asked to submit the assignment (Answer prepared after the deadline are
not considered) onto a server/ drive to which the whole students-group have access (read
and write not delete). State precisely (step wise) the protocol for submission and
verification. Note that Prof. Palam has no individual shared key with the students for
scalability issues. Justify your protocol

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question from the course's exam ( cyber security with blockchain) where the method used is public key cryptography and hash function.